# what is most likely used method to handle multiple keys to fetch an value using STL container?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, std

I have three keys and one associated value with that keys.
All the keys are integer value.

consider the following table

```
+-------+--------+------------+--------+
| EMPID | DEPTID | COLLEGE ID | RESULT |
| 1     | 1      | 1          | A      |
| 1     | 2      | 2          | B      |
| 1     | 3      | 3          | C      |
| 2     | 1      | 1          | D      |
| 2     | 2      | 2          | E      |
| 2     | 3      | 3          | F      |
+-------+--------+------------+--------+
```

which among the following method is best?

**Method1: Key as string**

```
string key; /* EMPID:DEPTID:COLLEGE ID */
std::map<int,string> l_container;
```

**Method2: Using nested maps**

```
int key1 ; /* =EMPID */
int key2; /* =DEPTID */
int key3; /* =COLLEGE ID */
std::map<int,std::map<int,std::map<int,string>>> l_container;
```

Comment: this `std::map<key1,std::map<key2,std::map<key3,value>>>` does not compile. Have you think of `using key1=EMPIDl;`?

Comment: `std::map<std::tuple<key1, key2, key3>, result>`

Comment: @PiotrNycz edited the post

Comment: Change your table.  Your tables should be set up for a 1:1 relationship between key and value(s).  See [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) on how to change tables.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Denormalized for performance.. Lol..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - first create class that defines what you need from such container. I believe it would be something like this:

```
class ResultTable
{
public:
   void addResult(int key1, int key2, int key3, std::string value);
   void removeResult(int key1, int key2, int key3);
   std::string getResult(int key1, int key2, int key3) const;
   bool isPresent(int key1, int key2, int key3) const;
private:
  ... m_table; // real container here   
};
```

So, it is not so much important what you have behind `ResultsTable` in its private part. With such approach, you are free to change it when you find one method better than other...

So lets discuss what to put in private parts:

> **Method1: Key as string**
>
> ```
> std::map<std::string,std::string> m_table;
> ```

That would work - but I really discourage you to use it. That is unnecessary complicated and you would for sure see performance degradation in case of big number of results...

> **Method2: Using nested maps**
>
> ```
> std::map<int,std::map<int,std::map<int,std::string>>> l_container;
> ```

This method has disadvantage when comes to remove keys from map. It might happen that you left nested maps empty after removing last element...

**Method3: Using combined keys maps**

```
std::map<std::tuple<int,int,int>, std::string> m_data;
// or
std::map<std::array<int,3>, std::string> m_data;
```

This method (already mentioned in comments) should be the best. I personally  prefer the version with `std::array` for key consisting of elements of the same type (`int` here).